# Enclosing external jQuery file in $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have external JavaScript files that contain only jQuery.  Should I enclose all of the code in each of these external files in $`(document).ready()`? What is the best practice here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the jquery script above them in your page, and have each of the other scripts included after it, in the normal way. But inside each of those scripts, put all the necessary code in the $(document).ready() structure. You can use it multiple times; you aren't restricted to just once.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I enclose all of the code in each of these external files in $(document).ready()?

Only if they need to wait for the DOM to be complete before they run.

> What is the best practice here?

Combining them into one file, minifying it and serving it with appropriate HTTP compression and cache control it.