# Jquery - How do you convert the $(document).ready() into a js file?

Tags: jquery

I have a ton of jquery code in the .ready()

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   //jQuery goodness in here.
```

How do I take all the code and just make it a .js file so I can just reference the script like any other script? Should i minify it? How do I do that?

I read this post: [Enclosing external jQuery file in $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834429/enclosing-external-jquery-file-in-document-ready)

But it didn't help because I'm not sure how to actually implement it. Do I just copy the code exactly how it is and save it as a .js file? Then what about the minify process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***Step 1.*** Create file *myfile.js* with contents:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
       // .... your jQuery goodness .... 
 });
```

***Step 2.*** In your HTML page, first include jQuery, then include myfile.js (in that order).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

***Step 3.*** PROFIT!

***Step 4. (OPTIONAL)*** Minify your *myfile.js* using http://jscompress.com/ or whatever else minifier you want to use.

Comment: "PROFIT!" HAHAHAHA! Nice!

Comment: I work with asp.net core 2.2 and have VARIOUS .cshtm.files (views) with  $(document).ready( function() { .... So.. the goal is, to run the code, if the SPECIFIC .cshtml file is loaded completely. I think, to put the code in a .central .js file only work, if only ONE .cshtml is included in the solution...? Or how does $(document).ready(... know, WHICH document has to be loaded to run the code? Or - alternatively - one .cs file has to be created for EACH .cshtml-file (view) what is not nice...?

Comment: I think, the best (cleanest) solution for my case (see my last comment) would be, to leave the $(document).ready( function() { ..on the .cshtml-files (view), create specific functions (for each view) for the "ready code" in the .js file and then call it from the $(document).ready( function() { ... of the .cshtml.file (view). This way, further also a global "ready code" function can be created and be called (in addition to the "view specific code") from each view (if needed)...

Comment: @FredyWenger, your `$(document).ready()` function is always included inside of the `<script></script>` tags. There is no difference in behaviour of this, or any other JS function, if it is specified inline, or loaded as a part of .js file. `document` points to the DOM of your currently used .cshtml file, loaded in the browser. It doesn't care how much such files you have on the server side

Answer (score 1):

You can write all your codes in a function and call it when dom's ready. 
Minify is recommended for make you js smaller -> faster loaded. You can find many online js compressors, such as http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/